# VS 2010 Beta 2: where is the Visual Studio command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Consider a fresh install of Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. In this case, the web-downloader was used, but that's unlikely relevant.

The Visual Studio Command Prompt is missing.

[image: start menu]

I had expected it to be there, just like 2005 & 2008. The intention is to call `aspnet_regsql` without having to navigate to its path at `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\`, or having to add that path to the environment variables. Doing either of those would be quick, but the idea is to be able to reuse the Command Prompt more than once.

**Questions**:

- is there a way to create the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt?
- is there a VS menu option to get to this Command Prompt?
- any guesses on why Microsoft didn't include this shortcut?

Comment: More issues/defects for VS 2010 Beta 2: http://bit.ly/3st8Yl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you install C++? If not, that's a known issue in Beta 2 - the prompt shortcut is not being added when C++ is not installed

Comment: Indeed, this install did NOT have C++ installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-install the application with the C++ IDE. That will save the time you would spend on installing C++ debugger.